# Drawing lines from tangents from two circles on both sides.

Tags: trigonometry, circles

I need to draw two red lines connecting the tangents from two circles on both sides. I need an algorithm that would get them based on any angle these circles are in relation to another. I need the results in `x, y` coordinates for plotting them. The part I am having trouble with is finding the `x, y` using the radius based on the angle which would give me the tangent. I am more than happy doing some research - just point me the right direction.

The circles will always be the same size.

Thanks for any help.

[image: Two intersecting circles]

[image: circles on angle]

[Something promising, yet no code or algorithm](http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/emt669/Student.Folders/Kertscher.Jeff/Essay.3/Tangents.html)

[Better Yet!](http://www.mathopenref.com/consttangentsext.html)

Comment: It's very hard to guess what you mean. What are the ellipses?

Comment: They are circles, they are being drawn to a canvas that uses `x, y` coordinates, and I want to draw a line from the center point on one to the center point on the other on both sides. Just the long lines not the short ones.

Comment: Why did you call them ellipses if they are circles?

Comment: You seem to be looking for the **tangent** to two **similar** ellipses which are aligned along the **major axis**.

Comment: I call them ellipses, since my program does.

Comment: Your question is really unclear, I've added some terminology above which may help you.

Comment: Thanks, feel free to correct me, I am not a big trigonometry guy.

Comment: Please try to fix the question, it doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: Not sure what to change. See the long red lines? That is what I need to draw no matter what angle the center points are at.

Comment: @SuzuHirose, does that help?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question properly, you have two circles of equal radii, and you want to draw the two common tangents on each side of the circle. The points of tangency to each circle fall on a line through the circle center that is perpendicular to the line connecting the centers (I know, I should really draw a picture, but it's too late at night). So if you know the centers and the common radius, it's easy to figure out the points of tangency, so you can determine the two red lines.

Comment: Thanks, I look up `Tangents`.

Comment: Seems like I need to find the angle the two circle are from each other using `x, y`. What would `2,2` to `5,4` be? Considering those are the center points on `2D`.

Comment: You don't need the angle; all you need is the slope of the line. The slope of that line is $\frac{4-2}{5-2} = \frac{2}{3}$, so that will be the slope of both tangent lines (and the slope of the lines connecting the two points of tangency to one of the circles will be $-\frac{3}{2}$).

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure how to graph that answer in 2D.

Comment: Since the tangent moves based on the difference in the circles, I say angle, would it be based on that angle somehow.